# How can I ensure that ASP.NET Core's IFormFile stream doesn't read more than what's specified in the file's Content-Length?

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload

I have an API endpoint for uploading large files, streaming then directly to DB. I use ASP.NET Core's `IFormFeature` to do this, calling `IFormFile.OpenReadStream()` to get a `Stream` that I pass to [SqlClient for streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support).

I want to enforce a a maximum file size to avoid abuse. I know `IFormFile` has a `Length` property, but I assume that is based on `Content-Length` or similar and can not be trusted (please correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK the only way to be 100% sure about the file size is to actually read the data; the client could send an incorrect `Content-Length`.)

I must therefore ensure that when the stream is read, it does not read more than what is specified in `IFormFile.Length` (ideally it should throw if it encounters additional bytes). I have not found a way to do this. Is this possible, or is there perhaps a better way to ensure the server doesn't read enormous amounts of data from clients sending incorrect Content-Length headers?

(It should go without saying that this must not entail reading the entire file into memory.)

Comment: If you're using `IFormFile`, the entire file is read into memory/disk, so `IFormFile.Length` will be the correct number of bytes.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#file-upload-scenarios

Comment: Oh, my bad. I have misread the docs, then.